# How to find dinamic xpath element

Tags: javascript, xpath, protractor

i have a web element who's xpath is dinamically generated but it ends with "_2".
The xpaths have the following format:

```
//*[@id="hNQjKwNtHyHqFtVtOQTm_2"]
//*[@id="dZcUekrklXsbv_AlImka_2"]
```

I've tried :

```
    //input[ends-with(@id,'_2')]"
    //*[contains(@id="_2")]'
```

and different combinations with contains but i had no luck. I can't seem to manage to do it, is there another way of doing this or can you help me understand what the problem is?

In protractor i get an error message informing me that the xpath is not valid

```
<input data-bind=" attr: { maxlength: maxlength, type: type, id: id, 'data-type': dataType, disabled: disabled, 'aria-disabled': disabled, 'pattern': pattern, 'inputmode': 'numeric', 'max': $data.max, 'min': $data.min, 'step': $data.step, 'tabindex': $data.tabIndex, 'aria-invalid': isInvalid, 'aria-label': label }, value: val, valueUpdate: valueUpdate, css: { error: $data.err, hasFocus: hasFocus, hideCaret: $data.hideCaret, hasValue: hasValue }, event: { focus: onFocus, blur: onBlur }" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" formnovalidate="" required="" maxlength="11" type="tel" id="dZcUekrklXsbv_AlImka_2" pattern="[0-9]*" tabindex="2000" aria-invalid="true" class="">
```

Comment: And is `dZcUekrklXsbv_AlImka_2` (in your sample html) the desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting no, i just want to click it or send keys to it, all of the elements of this page are generate dinamicaly and i saw that the id is always ending with "_2" and though i could manage to find it somehow

Comment: you can use js path of element, **element(by.css(js_path))** . js_path should be in **""** or **''**

Answer (score 2):

Your first xpath expression

```
//input[ends-with(@id,'_2')]
```

should normally work. Unfortunately, your system probabaly supports only xpath 1.0 and `ends-with()` is an xpath 2.0 expression.

You can try hacking around that limitation by using

```
//input[substring(@id,string-length(@id)-1 )="_2"]
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried your solution and i got : "Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //input[substring(@id,string-length(@id)-1 )="_2"])"

Comment: @AnghelAlexandru Well, the expression definitely works on the sample html in your question. So the problem may be with your actual html or maybe your script.

Comment: i'm using protractor which as you guessed supports only xpath 1.0... do you think there's a way to find the element by knowing what the ID ends with? instead of xpath? i've searched online and found something on stackoverflow but doesn't seem quite right to me

Comment: @AnghelAlexandru I'm afraid I don't know of an alternative to xpath here. But just FYI, both `string-length()` and `substring()` are xpath 1.0 methods so they should work. The error says the target element can't be found, which means it's something in the html, not the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `xpath` using `contains()` is wrong.

Try this.

```
//input[contains(@id,"_2")]
```

Comment: i've tried it, still doesn't work, says it doesn't find it